# How to modify each char code of JNI String?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I have a function in my class for android.

```
    private String modify(String s) {
        char[] o = s.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
            int x = o[i];
            o[i] = (char) (x - 125);
        }
        return String.valueOf(o);
    }
```

I want to implement similar functionality in JNI method. Means, take a JNI String, convert to char array, modifify charcode of each char in char array and return JNI string from modified char array.

Will you please guide me?

Comment: This is a broad question and not focused enough. Did you try anything? What is the target platform? In what programming language should the native code be? And most importantly: *Why do you want to do this?*

Comment: What did you try so far? We can't provide guidance if we don't know where you currently are in your endeavor and what problems you're running into. Also, is there a real world reason behind it (if so, which?) or is this for academic reasons? What does your code do for character codes smaller than 125?

Comment: In my android app written in java, I used this function to get original string form a modified string resides in string resource. But decompilation of the app shows this function mostly readable. I want to implement similar method (as library is hard to decompile) in JNI function in my "keys.c" of jni folder. Due to lack of knowledge in c, I can't figure out the proper process to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jni you can get `const jchar*` for a `jstring` with `GetStringChars`, locally store new jchar values in array and return it as a new String. Code follows:

C++ Version

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_jnitester_MainActivity_modify(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject /* this */,
        jstring str) {

    // Get jchar (2 bytes - its in unicode - not UTF) array of java string.
    // This can only be const jchar*, so you cannot modify it.
    jsize len = env->GetStringLength(str);
    jboolean isCopy;
    const jchar * strChars = env->GetStringChars(str, &isCopy);

    // Prepare new array of jchar, which will store new value
    std::vector<jchar> newStr;
    newStr.resize(len);

    // Do logic on it
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < newStr.size(); i++) {
        int x = strChars[i];
        newStr[i] = (char) (x - 125);
    }

    if (isCopy == JNI_TRUE) {
        env->ReleaseStringChars(str, strChars);
    }

    // Return as a new java string
    return env->NewString(newStr.data(), newStr.size());
}
```

C only version:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <memory.h>

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_jnitester_MainActivity_modify(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject this,
        jstring str) {

    // Get jchar (2 bytes - its in unicode - not UTF) array of java string.
    // This can only be const jchar*, so you cannot modify it.
    jsize len = (*env)->GetStringLength(env, str);
    jboolean isCopy;
    const jchar * strChars = (*env)->GetStringChars(env, str, &isCopy);

    // Prepare new array of jchar, which will store new value
    jchar* newStr = (jchar*)malloc(len * 2 + 2);

    // Do logic on it
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        int x = strChars[i];
        newStr[i] = (char) (x - 125);
    }

    if (isCopy == JNI_TRUE) {
       (*env)->ReleaseStringChars(env, str, strChars);
    }

    // Return as a new java string
    jstring resStr = (*env)->NewString(env, newStr, len);
    free(newStr);
    return resStr;
}
```

Comment: ```#include <vector>``` shows error: vector file not found.

Comment: @GourangaDas you probably use only C in your application, I have provided C only version. By default AndroidStudio allows C++ code in native projects.

Comment: The way you call `JNIEnv` functions is slightly different in C. Instead of `env->GetStringLength(str);` you'd use `(*env)->GetStringLength(env, str);`, etc.